# How to remove all items from ArrayList in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have an array list in kotlin and I want to remove all item from it, leave it as an empty array to start adding new dynamic data. i tried `ArrayList.remove(index)` `arrayList.drop(index)` but none works,

The Declaration:

```
var fromAutoCompleteArray: List<String> = ArrayList()
```

here is how I try it :

```
for (item in fromAutoCompleteArray){
        fromAutoCompleteArray.remove(0)
             }
```

I'm using the `addTextChangedListener` to remove old data and add new data based on user's input:

```
    private fun settingToAutoComplete() {
        val toAutoCompleteTextView: AutoCompleteTextView =
            findViewById<AutoCompleteTextView>(R.id.toAutoCompleteText)
        toAutoCompleteTextView.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {
            }

            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {
                doLocationSearch(toAutoCompleteTextView.text.toString(), 2)

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
                toAutoCompleteTextView.postDelayed({
                    toAutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown()
                }, 10)
            }

        })
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, toAutoCompleteArray)
        toAutoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter)
        toAutoCompleteTextView.postDelayed({
            toAutoCompleteTextView.setText("")
            toAutoCompleteTextView.showDropDown()
        }, 10)
    }
```

And here is the function that adds the data :

```
    private fun doLocationSearch(keyword: String, fromTo: Number) {
        val baseURL = "api.tomtom.com"
        val versionNumber = 2
        val apiKey = "******************"
        val url =
            "https://$baseURL/search/$versionNumber/search/$keyword.json?key=$apiKey"
        val client = OkHttpClient()
        val request = Request.Builder().url(url).build()
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: okhttp3.Response) {
                val body = response.body?.string()
                println("new response is : $body")
                val gson = GsonBuilder().create()
                val theFeed = gson.fromJson(body, TheFeed::class.java)
                if (theFeed.results != null) {
                    for (item in theFeed.results) {
                        println("result address ${item.address.freeformAddress} ")
                        if (fromTo == 1) {
                            fromAutoCompleteArray = fromAutoCompleteArray + item.address.freeformAddress
                            println(fromAutoCompleteArray.size)
                        } else {
                            toAutoCompleteArray = toAutoCompleteArray + item.address.freeformAddress
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    println("No Locations found")
                }


            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
                println("Failed to get the data!!")
            }
        })

    }
```

and as you see the line `println(fromAutoCompleteArray.size)` shows me if it's deleted or not, and it is always encreasing.

Also, tried to use `clear()` without a loop and none works:

`fromAutoCompleteArray.clear()`

Comment: Can you post the list declaration please

Comment: And also the following code that makes you think it isn't empty.

Comment: @AjahnCharles added complete details on the function and the textview

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The `List` type in Kotlin is not mutable. If you want to cause your list to change, you need to declare it as a `MutableList`.

I would suggest changing this line:

```
var fromAutoCompleteArray: List<String> = ArrayList()
```

To this:

```
val fromAutoCompleteArray: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
```

And then you should be able to call any of these:

```
fromAutoCompleteArray.clear()     // <--- Removes all elements
fromAutoCompleteArray.removeAt(0) // <--- Removes the first element
```

I also recommend `mutableListOf()` over instantiating an `ArrayList` yourself. Kotlin has sensible defaults and it is a bit easier to read. It will end up doing the same thing either way for the most part.

It is also preferable to use `val` over `var`, whenever possible.

**Update**: Vals not vars, thanks for spotting that Alexey

Comment: Also worth mentioning: prefer `val` over `var`.

Comment: Good point @AlexeyRomanov. I was in a hurry and didn't recommend that. Updated!

Answer (score 0):

i dont know how how you declare arraylist but this can be done as following

```
var arrayone: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf("one","two","three")

val arraytwo = arrayone.drop(2)

for (item in arraytwo) {
  println(item) // now prints all except the first one...
}
```

in your case try this

```
val arraytwo = fromAutoCompleteArray.toMutableList().apply { 
  removeAt(0)
}
```

Comment: What is the need for second array?